# Failsafe method of executing a script

Tags: shell

I want to execute a script from a parent folder that goes inside several subdirectories, so that after the script is done inside each folder it goes into the next. My problem is that sometimes I have folders were the main file, that I want to run the script on, does not exist (inside the folder) or I have a file whose name matches the criteria I imposed on the folders. So how would I make the script "failsafe" that even if it would not encounter the proper file or if the directory is actually a file it would go onto the next directory?

What I have written so far is something simple

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ????Z????; do

cd "$dir" || exit

awk '{print $1, $4, $5, $6}' 18_12* >> attempt1

sed '/^#/ d' <attempt1> attempt2

sed 's/^/2 2 1 /' <attempt2> disp.BDCOBP11

for file in ./*EHZ
do
[[ -e "$file" ]] || break
sta1=$(echo "$file" | gawk -FZ '{print $1}')
sta2=$(echo "$file" | gawk -FZ '{print $2}')
mv disp.BDCOBP11 disp."${sta1}""${sta2}"
done

rm attempt1

cd ..

done
```

Inside each folder there is the 18_12* file and another *EHZ file, all the folders are like this:

```
AAAAZBBBB
ABCDZ1234
```

etc

Comment: Didn't I already give you advice on this last time you asked? Don't use `cd ..` in scripts; instead, scope your `cd "$dir"` in a subshell, so it's automatically undone when the subshell exits.

Comment: And make sure you test whether the `cd` fails, and avoid running any code that assumes it succeeded if not. This is covered by shellcheck warning [SC2164](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164).

Comment: ...really, you should run *all* your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it finds before asking a question. Right now there are lots of separate, unrelated bugs in here: [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), etc; we need a SO question to be narrowed to have only one problem you're asking about.

Comment: Yes you did! I was just wondering how I would structure it with having more lines, I looked into double vertical bars but could not find an answer for this situation.

Comment: OK, thanks I will look into it!

Comment: Also, it'd be much faster (and less buggy) to run `sta1=${file%%Z*}; sta2=${file#*Z}` instead of involving `awk`, `cut` or another external command in that process.

Comment: BTW, why are you storing `attempt1` and `attempt2` files? `awk '/^#/ { next } {print "2 2 1 " $1, $4, $5, $6}' 18_12* > disp.BDCOBP11` does the whole thing in one pass with no temporary files needed, and using only `awk` with no need for `sed`.

Comment: Even if you wanted to *keep* `sed`, though, `awk '{print $1, $4, $5, $6}' 18_12* | sed '/^#/ d' | sed 's/^/2 2 1 /' >disp.BDCOBP11` avoids the need for temporary files, feeding awk's stdout straight to the first sed, sed's stdout straight to the second sed, and the second sed's stdout straight to the output file.

Comment: At first I did it because I am new to this so I wanted to take things step by step, but thanks for the info! I updated my code, could you take a look at it and see if it would do what I was asking in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209456/discussion-between-miro-feliciano-and-charles-duffy).